# Glimpse button not available

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I installed Glimpse and run my app. I don't see the Glimpse icon in the bottom of the screen. It was a pretty simple installation process so I may have missed something, but perz the blogs it looks like I did everything I needed to do.

When I go to Glimpse.axd, it tells me: glimpseState = On, IP = ::1, On=True. It also says that my blacklisted plugins are: Request and MetaData. (I don't know if this is standard, or an indication that something is wrong).

Any ideas on where the full list of steps are at?

Software Installed: VS 2010, SP1 and NuGet, C#,
Razor viewengine,
Glimpse.Mvc3 0.85,
IE 9 and FF6,
a link to jquery is on every page

Oh yeah - when I run my app the url is "http://localhost:52160/"  I see in the webconfig file a section about environments and it had an entry "localhost:33333" so I changed it to "localhost:52160" to see if that might help. Didn't seem to affect anything.

Confused...

Comment: Your web.config is highly unusual for a fresh install of Glimpse. Can you share the Glimpse section of your web.config?

Comment: Sometimes you have to ask the right question, which you did. In the process of trying to get Glimpse working, I saw a blog post that said 'This is what your web.config should look like.' So i copied that and tried again to no avail. Your question made me realize that web.config is probably corrupt. So I wiped out my web.config and reinstalled Glimpse from scratch. Now it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness sake, the Glimpse NuGet package will automatically set the web.config settings for you.

If you are not using the NuGet package, you can see how to set up your web.config here: http://glimpse.codeplex.com/documentation